# pick group by from a col where col2 is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I have to write a report by doing some SQL in MS SQL server. The data I have is like this:

```
UserID,Country, CommNumber
00001, IN, 1001
00002, IN, NULL
00003, US, 1002
00004, US, 1003
00005, DE, NULL
00006, DE, NULL
00007, US, NULL
```

Now I want to pull up the list of countries where all CommNumbers are NULL. Even if one user has a CommNumber in that country, I don't want that country to be in list. So looking at above only DE has all two users with NULL on CommNumber. US and IN have atleast one user where the CommNumber is not NULL.

Hope this question makes sense.

My attempt is:

```
SELECT
[COUNTRY]
,COUNT(*) AS 'COMMNUMBER_USERS'
FROM
<TABLENAME> 
WHERE [COMMNUMBER] IS NULL
GROUP BY [C]
ORDER BY [COMMNUMBER_USERS]
```

The above is not giving me the correct results. I understand why because I don't have way to tell it that I only want countries where all commnumbers are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table t1 WHERE t1.Country = t.Country AND t1.CommNumber IS NOT NULL);
```

If you want only `Country` then you can do aggregation :

```
select country
from table t
group by country
having max(commnumber) is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `group by` and `having`:

```
select country
from t
group by country
having max(commnumber) is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using correlated subquery

```
select * from tablename a where not exists 
   (select 1 from tablename b where a.country=b.country and b.commnumber is not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT Country
FROM Tablename
GROUP BY Country
HAVING sum(ISNULL(Commnumber, 0)) = 0

You can use this one as well